# Save Images Faser with Pillow

Tags: python, performance, save, python-imaging-library

Question: Is there a faser way to save pictures with Pillow in Python?

what happened up to here:

I have a code that creates an image. The image is created by a function. Each pixel of the image is created and should be saved as a single image.

If I do not save this, the calculation runs about 9 sec. If I save it it is 20 sec. Ergo more than 50% of the time is used for saving. It gets even worse when the images get bigger.

The bottelneck is the saving. I switched from PNG -> JPEG, which is about 40% faster.

Is there another way to speed up saving?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np

MAX_ITER = 80
def mandelbrot(c):
    z = 0
    n = 0
    while abs(z) <= 2 and n < MAX_ITER:
        z = z*z + c
        n += 1
    return n

WIDTH = 140
HEIGHT = 96

RE_START = -2
RE_END = 1
IM_START = -1
IM_END = 1

palette = []
im = Image.new('RGB', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), (0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

n = 0
for x in range(0, WIDTH):
    for y in range(0, HEIGHT):
        c = complex(RE_START + (x / WIDTH) * (RE_END - RE_START),
                    IM_START + (y / HEIGHT) * (IM_END - IM_START))
        m = mandelbrot(c)
        color = 255 - int(m * 255 / MAX_ITER)
        draw.point([x, y], (color, color, color))

        im.save(f'test/output_{n}.jpg', 'JPEG')
        n = n + 1
```

Soucre: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2358/how-to-plot-the-mandelbrot-set/mandelbrot-set

Comment: Why do you want to create 13 440 images with just one pixel that is changing in the first place?

Comment: Would you be able to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/index.html)?

Comment: no point of using jpg or png when saving single pixel. Try [bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), notice how single-pixle file looks like for few pixels (which bytes change), convert your colors to bytes and substitute just that changing part for each file.

Comment: Hello, thanks for ur answers: Jérôme Richard -> Yes and later make a video out of it. 

Lone Survivr: Calculation time is not the Problem, thereby I will not benefit from it.

dankal444: Nice Idea, but i guess it's mutch slower than what I do, i will try to multiprocess the saving Operation and see if i get a benefit from that.

Comment: The best solution is then to create the video on the fly in RAM (see: [in-situ processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-situ_processing)) since writing 13K files (180Mo in BMP) is going to take some time and reading them back too (even on SSD due to limited IOPS). I think the whole operation could be done in less than a second (the encoding part is probably the most time-consuming). OpenCV and FFMPEG should be able to do that.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard I really do like ur idea. First of all i thought, that generating the picture in an 3d numay array(HEIGHT, WITH, (Pixelpoint, R,G,B)) with multiprocessing as saving operation would do the trick but it does not.
I am allready using FFMPEG for making the video afterwards (Post-Picture-Generating-Operation)^^, how can I implement that?

Comment: I am totally unfamiliar with the FFMPEG library (I only used it few times in bash). I guess the 3D array should be fine here since the amount of data is relatively small (as long as you do not increase the size of the image). Note that you could use 1 byte to store a pixel since R=G=B. Also note that If the speed of the mandelbrot function is a problem, you could use Numba or Cython to speed it up.